# Java SWT Spinner with text inside?

Tags: swt, spinner, rcp, jface, equinox

I have JAVA SWT/RCP application (Equinox OSGi), I am just creating Wizard which should look like one the picture:

[image]

The problem I just caught that standard SWT class Spinner, does not offer this kind of option to have some text inside of Spinner. I was doing some googling but I could not find any reasonable solution for this.

Spinner (with text) like described on my picture, is possible to do with Swing, but I cannot use Swing => SWT RCP (Equinox OSGi platform).

I even looked into SWT Spinner class source but its not very clear.

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to implement custom widget. If you look at `Spinner`, it is also a `Composite`. you could do the same, with a `Text` widget and up arrow `Button` and down arrow `Button`.

Comment: It is not so simple, because those widgets are calling OS implementation... I looked into the code and its not very simple way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [SWT Combo](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Combo.html) widget to simulate a Swing Spinner.

Here's some example code.

```
private String[] items = { "5 min", "3 min", "1 min" };

Combo readOnlyCombo = new Combo(shell, SWT.DROP_DOWN | SWT.READ_ONLY);
readOnlyCombo.setItems(items);
```

Comment: This is not a good solution, if there are 60 or more records :(